# How to remove Hadoop parallelizing overhead?

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, overhead

Any clustering system including Hadoop has both benefits and harms. Benefits is ability to compute in parallel, harms are overhead for task distribution.

Suppose I don't want to have any benefits and using one node. How can I run Hadoop to completely avoid overhead? Is running on single node pseudodistributed node sufficient? Or it will still have some parallelizing overhead?

Comment: What kind of overhead you are talking about. Could you please explain with an example.

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli I don't know what kind of overhead. Any kind of it. My goal is to check how it is affecting.

Comment: With a single node, what's the point of even using Hadoop? You still obviously have the overhead of every single process stuck on a single machine... The distributed networking "overhead" outweighs the negatives... If you don't want Hadoop, then don't use it. Go switch to Mesos+Spark+Cassandra